# JSON ClassCastException

Tags: java, json

Folks I am trying to populate a bean from a JSONOject but its throwing me the exception online 64:
"**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String incompatible with net.sf.json.JSONObject**
"

```
 61: for( Object myObject : studentsGradeArray )
 62:   {
 63:
 64:    JSONObject studentGradeJSON = (JSONObject) myObject;
```

What could be the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you are getting a `String` object instead of the `JSONObject` that you require. Assuming that all objects in `studentsGradeArray` are supposed to be JSON Objects...

```
for( Object myObject : studentsGradeArray ) {
    JSONObject studentGradeJSON = JSONObject.fromObject(myObject);
    // the rest of your code
}
```

More information can be found in the [JSONObject documentation](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: Thanks NT3RP.. which ones more reliable. Your solution or amadeus's? Because you have added the cast from String as well.

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming you were using [this library](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html). I'll correct my answer.

Comment: Actually I do have this library imported in my class "import net.sf.json.JSONObject;"

Comment: My answer has been updated to use the proper API; let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks NT3RP, Exception is gone :)

Answer (score 0):

The elements of studentsGradeArray are of type String, not of type JSONObject.

You may want to say

```
JSONObject studentGradeJSON = new JSONObject(myObject)
```